# Storing text and images in firebase

Tags: firebase

I am creating an app which lets the user to create a business flyer. Now it would be having three things:-

1.Image

2.text

3.text

Now I want to store these 3 things in firebase so that I can share them with other users. I need a direction.
I want to just store the these three things nothing else.
I am using android for now.

Comment: Hi @The lifestyle Portrayer, Can you tell us what you tried so far in the process and what actual problem are you facing

Comment: Hey @Tamir Klein, I am new to firebase so I need a way to store all that stuff at one place. I don't have any code right now because I don't know what to do.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Firebase has a really handy Getting Started Guide which will show you how to read and write data, work with users, rules etc. The first place to start is to go through that guide - and you can select from the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) or [FireStore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/). Go through the guides and when you get stuck with a specific coding issue, ask about it here and we'll take a look! Be sure to indicate your platform as well. Voting to close the question as it won't be useful to future readers.

Comment: use firebase documentation. It will help you. here is the [link](https://firebase.google.com/)